# LanguageApp.translate() causes onEdit(e) to fail

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps, google-language-api

I am trying to write a function in Google Apps Script that triggers whenever a cell is edited in the Google Sheet in which the script is embedded. The purpose of the function is to automatically add the English translation as a note on the edited cell. Here is my code:

```
function onEdit(e){
  var range = e.range;
  var content = range.getValue();
  var translation = LanguageApp.translate(content, "auto", "en");

  range.setNote(translation);
}
```

The function runs when I edit a cell, however, it fails with the following message:

```
Invalid argument: source
    at onEdit(Code:4)
```

The problem seems to be LanguageApp.translate(), because if I don't use this one, it works. Can anyone help?

Comment: You can't use `auto` because it is not supported, have a look at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57076471/how-to-return-the-auto-detected-language-from-languageapp-translate) for some workarounds.

Comment: So using LanguageApp.translate() I can't have the language be automatically detected? :(

Comment: no, unfortunately `auto` detection is not supported yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**"auto"** is not a valid argument in LanguageApp.translate. Please see valid language codes here:

[Language Support](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/languages)

Comment: So using LanguageApp.translate() I can't have the language be automatically detected? :(